# Usando model.find() com LIKE no mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Eu tenho uma função aqui pra fazer uma busca no MongoDB usando o mongoose, porém eu gostaria que ele encontrasse Brasil quando eu pesquisasse por bra, Bra, Sil, sil, etc. Eu olhei na documentação e segui o exemplo mas não deu certo, ele não retorna nada. Segue o código:

```
exports.postSearchCountry = (req, res, next) => {
        const countryName = req.body.countryName
        Country.find({
            name: /countryName/i
        })
        .then(countries => {
            res.render('country/countries', {
                countries: countries
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando usar uma expressão regular para fazer a pesquisa, mas não está gerando uma expressão regular dinamicamente. A expressão `/countryName/i` irá pesquisar por países que contenham literalmente "countryName" em seu nome, não que contenham o valor da variável countryName.

Para gerar uma expressão regular dinamicamente, use `new RegExp(countryName, 'i')`, ou seja

```
Country.find({
    name: new RegExp(countryName, 'i')
})
```

Porém quero te alertar que não é essa a forma de se utilizar expressões regulares em Mongoose que eu conheço, se essa maneira não funcionar, utilize

```
Country.find({
    name: { $regex: new RegExp(countryName), $options: 'i' }
})
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo.

No exemplo da documentação do mongoose eles usam uma string direto, por isso não foi necessário usar o new RegExp